# Create image shadow with CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to create CSS like this:

[image]

Please help me guys, actually create the shadow of the button.

Okay I have tried this and difficult to create the shadow:

CSS CODE

```
 a{ 
   display: inline-block;
   width:9px; 
   height:9px; 
   border-radius:50px; 
   font-size:20px; 
   color:#fff; 
   line-height:100px; 
   text-align:center; 
   text-decoration:none; 
   background-color: #1f1f1f !important; 
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important; 
   border: 1px #bebebd inset; 
 }

 a.active {
   display: inline-block;
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   border-radius:50px;
   font-size:20px;
   color:#fff;
   line-height:100px;
   text-align:center;
   text-decoration:none;
   background-color: #2880d7 !important;
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important;
   border: 0px;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="active"></a>
```

Please help me guys, actually create the shadow of the button.

Thank in advance

Comment: Yes this is my homework, I have tried these: <br />

Comment: <code> a{
    display: inline-block;
    width:9px;
    height:9px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #1f1f1f !important;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important;
    border: 1px #bebebd inset;
}</code>

Comment: <code>a.active{
    display: inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: #2880d7 !important;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important;
    border: 0px;
}</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a{ 
   display: inline-block;
   width:9px; 
   height:9px; 
   border-radius:50px; 
   font-size:20px; 
   color:#fff; 
   line-height:100px; 
   text-align:center; 
   text-decoration:none; 
   background-color: #1f1f1f !important; 
   margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px !important; 
   border: 1px #bebebd inset;  
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
 }
```

replace this with your css `a{}` class

If it is not enough to you, see this [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)

Comment: Hi ANK, thanks for your response, when we have seen that images, the describe that the shadows is inner shadow, how about that?

Comment: usingbox-shadow tag in CSS .a class. by this tag we have to set the the position of the horizontal shadow, the position of the vertical shadow, size of shadow and color of the shadow...

Comment: Thanks ANK, I have used your suggestion to use box-shadow.